# cURL into a Directory away from curl.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I'm trying to cURL videos from an FTP site to a directory in my project. Originally all the videos were in one folder on the FTP and my simple for loop for grabbing them worked great. Now I need to implement the ability to create subfolders on the FTP and have them save to the same subfolders in my directory. curl.exe is in the directory with my downloadMedia.bat and media_list.txt (simple video-per-line list of files to download). I manage to create the correct file structure by because I've changed my active directory to get there, when I try to curl the files, it can't find curl.exe. Any help? Here's my code so far.

```
@echo off

@set CONTENTPATH=../project/videos
@set FTPSERVER=ftp://my.ftp.com/videos

@mkdir "%CONTENTPATH%"

set /a c=0

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (media_list.txt) do (
    set /a c=c+1
)

@cd "%CONTENTPATH%"

for /l %%x in (1, 1, %c%) do (
   if exist "%%A" (
      @echo File '%%A' already exists
   ) else (
      @mkdir "%%A"
      @rmdir "%%A"
      curl -o "%%A" "%FTPSERVER%/%%A"
   )
)
```

I created `%c%` as a count because it couldn't find media_list.txt after I changed directory to my `%CONTENTPATH%`

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the contents of `media_list.txt` using the variables in your second for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use %%A outside of the for loop that declares it - unless you set it in a separate variable, i.e. `set variable=%%A`. 
In which case you need to `setLocal enableDelayedExpansion` at the start of your script - and call the variable as `!variable!` (wrapped with exclamation marks) as opposed to the usual `%variable%`.

Perhaps something like this will do what you want:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (media_list.txt) do (
    if exist "%CONTENTPATH%/%%A" (
        echo File '%%A' already exists
    ) else (
        mkdir "%CONTENTPATH%/%%A"
        rmdir "%CONTENTPATH%/%%A"
        curl -o "%CONTENTPATH%/%%A" "%FTPSERVER%/%%A"
    )
)
```

Each line will be a separate loop, where %%A will equal the text in that line.

Also, just a couple of syntax things; `set /a c+=1` is neater than `set /a c=c+1`, and if you have declared `echo off` at the start of your script you do not need to add `@` at the start of any following lines, unless you turn echo back on. But that's just me being pedantic.